# ¿ Cómo cambiar el estilo de la linea intermitente?

Tags: javascript

Cuando escribimos en un cuadro de texto, ya sea `input`, `textArea`, etc. Siempre tenemos una linea que nos dice en **donde vamos escribiendo**, y mi pregunta es,

¿Cómo puedo editar esa línea?, ya sea cambiándole el color, el grosor, el largo, el ancho, el ángulo de inclinación, etc, y desde `JavaScript` ? y además

¿Cuál es el nombre de esa línea, para así poder referirme de la manera correcta ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se llama cursor :P

Comment: Son los estilos del cursor. Mira esta pregunta como guía https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758023/how-to-use-this-square-cursor-in-a-html-input-field

Comment: Se llama Caret :)

Answer (score 4):

Se  llama `Caret` o `Cursor` y puede dar estilo con la propiedad [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) , *Ejm*

```css
input {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
    caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Solamente color ? y las demás propiedades no son posibles ?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian la propiedad sí , es solo para el color , más propiedades no estoy seguro. Sí hay más quizá tendrá una nueva respuesta pronto. :)